# Can I calculate the time it will take for the program to run if I know the arithmetic complexity?

Tags: time, complexity-theory

I am currently doing an assignment for finding prime numbers with Fermat's little theorem(it's compulsory) and the program I have (I think ) has complexity O(logn). For really large numbers, however, it drags on too much(we are talking about 1200 digits, size of that class) , like 8 minutes , and I don't know if this is normal. Is there a way to calculate average time for an input, while we know the complexity?

Answer (score 0):

If your algorithm has asymptotic time complexity f(n), what this tells you is that lim T(n+1)/T(n) = lim f(n+1)/f(n) as n goes to infinity. So, if you know N, f and T(N), and if N is already large enough that the asymptotic behavior is approximated, then you can estimate T(N+1) = T(N) * f(N+1) / f(N). To choose an N that is large enough, you'd need to know about the constant factors involved.